# Magento Show custom attribute dropdown option for a simple product in cart page

Tags: magento

how to Show custom attribute dropdown option  for a simple product in cart page

my attribute name is meal_time

`<?php
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
    echo $product->getAttributeText('meal_time');
?>`

Answer (score 0):

To get the custom attribute option in the cart , first we need to get quote visible product items and then load the product to get its options.

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cart as $item) {
       $product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        echo  $_product->getMealTime();
    }
```

Comment: But its not displaying drop down option its just displaying value see this link for screen shot    http://prntscr.com/8wjral

Answer (score 0):

To display all the option of an attribute

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cart as $item) {
       $product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')-getAttribute('catalog_product', 'meal_time');
      foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $instance) {
            echo $myattribute[$instance['value']] = $instance['label'];
            }
    }
```

If you want to display as select dropdown , use select tag including the label and value as options